# PHP + XPath Query get Child Nodes and their values

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xpathquery

I have a XML file record.xml which looks like:

```
<record>
    <name>john</name>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <subject>mathematics, english, science</subject>
</record>
<record>
    <name>jamie</name>
    <gender>female</gender>
    <subject>mathematics, science</subject>
</record>
<record>
    <name>jack</name>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <subject>social-science, english</subject>
</record>
```

I want to write a xpath query which will return all the child nodeName of `<record>` and value of all these child nodes in an associative array.

> For Ex.:
>
> For above XML file Output array should be-
>
> ```
> array{
>      [0] => array{
>                  [name] = 'john',
>                  [gender] = 'male',
>                  [subject] = 'mathematics, english, science' 
>             }
>      [1] => array{
>                  [name] = 'jamie',
>                  [gender] = 'female',
>                  [subject] = 'mathematics, science' 
>             }
>      [2] => array{
>                  [name] = 'jack',
>                  [gender] = 'male',
>                  [subject] = 'social-science, english' 
>             }
> }
> ```

Below is part of Code I written this return all the `<record>` child nodes values but not their node name.

```
    .......
    .......
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('record.xml');
    $xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);
    $res = $xpathvar->query('//record');
    foreach($res as $data){
            //$data do not contain node values
           $arr[] = $data->textContent;
    }
    //process $arr to get required format
     .....
     .....
```

I just want a Xpath query which will return child node names along with their values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is a record as a node is just part of the node hierarchy. What you're getting is all records, however you also want to descend and get the data from the record's child nodes. A very case specific example is :

```
<?php     
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('record.xml');
$xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);
$res = $xpathvar->query('//record');
foreach($res as $data){
    $narr = [];
    foreach ($data->childNodes as $cnode) {
        $narr[$cnode->nodeName] = $cnode->nodeValue;
    }
    $arr[] = $narr;

}    
print_r($arr);
```

Should output something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => john
            [gender] => male
            [subject] => mathematics, english, science
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => jamie
            [gender] => female
            [subject] => mathematics, science
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => jack
            [gender] => male
            [subject] => social-science, english
        )

)
```

**NOTE:** This solution is very case specific and would probably break if you have additional nested hierarchies (which I recommend you do in order to store the multiple subjects).

Comment: well i think this will be good enough for me to proceed further. Thanks